# Quartz current executing job when Tomcat is killed

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

Something i am not clear on. Say i have jobs randomly scheduled throughout the day and each job takes 30 minutes to run. Say i have five of these jobs running and Tomcat gets killed. Do the jobs restart when i start Tomcat with my application, or are the currently running jobs lost because they already fired?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Short answer, by default, currently running Jobs are considered fired and are not recovered

..*but* you can set **requestRecovery** property when you build a Job (JobDetail) to tell Quartz to recover that running Jobs in case of crash a.k.a. "hard shutdown".

Quoting the official documentation [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.3.0/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-03) on the bottom of the page:

> **RequestsRecovery** - if a job "requests recovery", and it is executing during the time of a
>   'hard shutdown' of the scheduler (i.e. the process it is running
>   within crashes, or the machine is shut off), then it is re-executed
>   when the scheduler is started again. In this case, the
>   JobExecutionContext.isRecovering() method will return true.

So you can do for example:

```
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.*;

...

JobDetail job = newJob(MyJob.class)
           .withIdentity("myJob", "group1")
           .requestRecovery(true) //This is the guy!
           .build();

...
```

Answer (score -1):

Tomcat does not care about your job. It is your task to terminate the job correctly in your webapp when it is shut down.

Comment: what i am after is does Quartz retry the jobs which were currently executing or does Quartz throw them away, meaning quartz can not cleanly recover from a jvm crash where a user has no means to "terminate the job correctly"