# quartz jobDetail requestRecovery

Tags: quartz-scheduler, fault-tolerance

The documentation for `JobDetail.requestsRecovery` property states the following

> Instructs the Scheduler whether or not the Job  should be re-executed
>   if a 'recovery' or 'fail-over' situation is encountered.

Now, what is a 'recovery' situation or a 'fail-over' situation?

How are they different?

Does the recovery happen only if the JVM crashes during job execution or does it happen if the job execution fails because of an exception also?

Answer (score 18):

A "*Recovery situation*" is the generic term, one kind of recovery situation is the "*fail-over*".

A **fail-over** is a process used by fault-tolerance systems generally used with redundancy (e.g. clustering). Quartz use fail-over when is used in clustering and *more* Quartz "nodes" exists.

Quoting  [documentation](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ConfigJDBCJobStoreClustering):

> *Fail-over* occurs when one of the nodes fails while in the midst of executing one or more jobs. When a node fails, the other nodes detect the condition and identify the jobs in the database that were in progress within the failed node.
>   Any jobs marked for recovery (with the "requests recovery" property on the JobDetail) will be re-executed by the remaining nodes.

A **recovery situation** is every situation that produce an "Hard-shutdown" (i.e. the process it is running within crashes, or the machine is shut down).

---

To answer your second question:

- If the JVM crashes during a job execution > Quartz will recover the job

  (Because a crash is Recovery situation)
- if the job execution fails because of an exception > Quartz will not recover the job

  (Because exception is not an hard-shutdown, a *misfire* is thrown instead)

*See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139796/quartz-current-executing-job-when-tomcat-is-killed/19146877#19146877) answer to activate recovery for your jobs.*