# Quartz scheduler : start jobs when tomcat restart

Tags: java, tomcat, quartz-scheduler

I'm new in Quartz scheduler and I'm trying to configure some job using tomcat 7. So my problem is my jobs dosen't run after a restart of tomcat.

I did some search and I find that requestRecovery must resolve that issue ([response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139796/quartz-current-executing-job-when-tomcat-is-killed))

This is my job:

```
            JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                .newJob(WidgetExcelValueJob.class)
                .withIdentity(widgetJobEntity.getName(), widgetJobEntity.getGroupe())
                .requestRecovery(true).build();
```

this is my servlet in web.xml:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet
    </servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

When tomcat restarts the scheduler is started but not my jobs only if I create new trigger and excute :

```
scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
```

Comment: do I need to connect Quartz with database ?